# How to search for files only (excluding directories) in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

How do I search for files only?

I need to display all the files `*.*`  but without directories and subdirectories.

Of course I can just type `*.*`
 and sort it in a desired way, so it will display all data I need, but there are thousands of directories and it take "ages" to sort.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`System.Kind:`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows#section_3) advanced tag and to search for files only add the negation flag `<>` (which means not equal).

In the Windows Search bar, enter: `*.* System.Kind:<>folder` and this will exclude the results that are of the `folder` type from the search.

If you're on the command line: `dir *.* /a-d` will exclude directories in your search results.

These will still search recursively if specified (as is the default with Windows Search but you must specify the `/s` flag on the command line) but the results will not show any directories or sub-directories matching your search criteria.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect. Just wonder why Microsoft hide those options? Does anyone really need to search for Recorded TV programm?? There is such an option (might be different translation).

Comment: Just was going to ask this question, and found it.  It seems to me, btw, that the search in windows has actually became worse over the years (since 2000)....